# How to join 2 files based one key and selected some specific column?

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, gawk, join

I have 2 files and want to inner join them using `awk`. This is written using sql server :

```
SELECT [file1.column1],[file2.column2] FROM file1
INNER JOIN file2 on file2.column1 = file1.column5;
```

This is the file i want to join:

file1 :
[image]

file2:
[image]

so the key is column5 file1 and column1 file2.

How to write them in awk language?

Your help will be useful for me to learn this awk.

Comment: Could you possibly share some of the data and what you would want to see given that data? To write the thing with `awk` (or the standard `join` utility), things like what delimiter is used between the fields of the text matters.

Comment: welcome to U&L, this could also be done using `join`. can you provide in your question a sample of data, along with expected result ?

Comment: i have edited my question with picture @Kusalananda

Comment: i have edited my question with picture @Archemar

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/5132

Comment: im sorry sir. first time i post a question here @JdeBP

Comment: I can't copy and paste your sample data if it's a picture, so I'm much less likely to offer you a solution. Please [don't do that](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
join -t"|" -1 5 -2 1 -o 1.1 2.2 file1 file2
```

`-1 5` - Use the 5th column of file1
`-2 1` - Use the 1st column of file2
`-o 1.1 2.2`  - Print as output 1st column of 1st file, 2nd column of 2nd file

Comment: just 4 rows showed up and outputing error messages = 
name file: is not sorted @Guru

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is the tool of choice

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{id[$5]=0; next}{if ($1 in id) print $1, $2}' file1 file2
```